# ¿Cómo creo un archivo .txt usando os en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Mi problema es que quiero crear x numero de archivos txt usando os en python3. Estoy ejecutando el siguiente comando:

```
import os
import multiprocessing

for i in range(x):
            print(f"Creating file number: {i+1}")
            file_name = "file"+str(i+1)+".txt"  
            os.system( "open(file_name)" )
```

Por algún motivo sigo teniendo el mismo error:

> sh: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

¿Existe otra manera de crear estos archivos?

Comment: Sé que debería de usar "w+ cuando hago el comando open, pero al hacerlo recibo otro error de sintaxis.

Comment: El comando está mal. `os.system` ejecuta un comando del sistema operativo y obviamente el comando cambia según el S.O. Además por que necesitas del módulo `os` si puedes hacer `open(file_name, "w").close()`

Answer (score 0):

En tu código de ejemplo no estás generando ningún archivo. Me tomaré la libertad de modificarlo para que genere un archivo vacío:

```
for i in range(x):
    print(f"Creating file number: {i+1}")
    file_name = "file"+str(i+1)+".txt"
    open(file_name, 'w').close()
```

Ahora para abrir ese archivo con la aplicación por defecto del sistema no lo hagas con `os.system`, tienes la librería `subprocess` que te facilita la vida

```
import subprocess

for i in range(x):
    print(f"Creating file number: {i+1}")
    file_name = "file"+str(i+1)+".txt"
    open(file_name, 'w').close()
    subprocess.run(['open', file_name], check=False)
```